# Use excel files in android application

Tags: android, excel, sqlite

I have multiple long excel files on my computer that I need to use in my android application.
The excel files contains 10 000 rows and I was wondering how I could include it in the project so I can use it in the application on the phone. I know I should use some sort of database so I can use SQLite in the android application. How can that be done? Any links to tutorials?
thank you

Comment: **1** - If you want to read excel files, you'll have to resort to some third party library, so better if you use plain csv files. **2** - you need to study some tutorials on how to use SQLite in Android. Google is a gold mine. **3** - If something goes wrong, then come back and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Excel library  for this. First you need to parse the excel file and then store that data in your mobile database.
You can use the following URL for further clarification.

> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html